# JQuery: Ajax .load question

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table of recent web guest who have registered.  One of the columns is a simple "send email" link that I hi-jack with Jquery when it's clicked and fire off an ajax .load to a backend php script that emails the person.

What I can't figure out, is how to simply change the link that was clicked on to something like "Sent!" and it's no longer a link.

The code is:

```
$(".sendEmail").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var guest_id = element.attr("id");                                         
$.post("WebGuest_SendEmail.php",{id: guest_id}, function(data) {
    $(this).html(data);  //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE ON SUCCESS.
    });                            
return false;                              
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would let the user know what is happening and then tell them what happened. So, tell them when it is sending and then tell them when it *has* been sent.

Like so:

```
$(".sendEmail").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var guest_id  = element.attr("id");
    element.replaceWith('Sending...');                                                                               
    $.post("WebGuest_SendEmail.php",{id: guest_id}, function(data) {
        $(this).html(data);  //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE ON SUCCESS.
        element.replaceWith('Sent!');
    });                                                    
    return false;                                                      
});
```

Of course, you'd probably want to revert back to an  if the backend script failed for some reason. If you are interested in techniques for that, let me know and I will explain that in more detail with best practices and such.

Comment: All the above solutions seem to work, thanks to each of you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do would be to just replace the link with some text.  Basically, we're just using the jQuery replaceWith() function on the calling anchor element.  Here's a simplified example of a complete HTML file to do what you want.

```
<script src="lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sendEmail").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    $.post("test.html", {}, function(data) {
      element.replaceWith("Sent!");    
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>

<a href="#" class="sendEmail">click me</a>
```

Comment: Oops, I should clarify.  Cut and paste the above example into a file called "test.html" and provide an appropriate path to jquery.js.

Comment: it is not necessary to wait for the data to arrive to replace the link with the text as I think

Comment: Realistically, how you inform the user is a much more complex problem than what this sample code demonstrates.  I'm strictly answering the question here by showing where the replaceWith() call would go.  KyleFarris' solution of replacing the text with "Sending..." in the interim is an even better idea, with the caveat that if you want to deal gracefully with server side errors then you need to check your result codes, render an error message and restore the original link.

Answer (score 2):

you can replace the link with the text "Sent!":

```
$(".sendEmail").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var guest_id = element.attr("id");
element.replaceWith('Sent!');
$.post("WebGuest_SendEmail.php",{id: guest_id}, function(data) {
        $("#container").html(data);  //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE ON SUCCESS.

    });                                                    
return false;                                                      
});
```